# Solutions of constant coefficients differential operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, linear-pde

Let $D$ be a constant coefficients linear differential operator on complex valued functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\tilde D=\mathbb{F}^{-1}\circ D\circ \mathbb{F}$ be its conjugation with the Fourier transform, thus $\tilde D$ is a polynomial on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Let us assume that $\tilde D$ does not vanish. Does it tell something on non-zero solutions of the equation $Du=0$?**

A basic example is $D=-\Delta +1$.

**Remark.** As far as I understand it follows that $u$ does not belong to the Schwatz space of tempered growth distributions.

Comment: You are right: if such a $u$ belongs to ${\cal S}'(R^n)$, then $u=0$.

Comment: On the other hand, without growth restrictions at infinity, no conclusions can be drawn (for example $D=-d^2/dx^2+1$ has the solutions $u=e^{\pm x}$).

Comment: @ChristianRemling : What is wrong with the exponent?